# cmake RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY does not work for CodeBlocks on linux

Tags: linux, cmake, codeblocks

In CodeBlocks, the `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` seems been hard coded to`${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin`, you can not change it. 
For example, if you set,
`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/debug)`
or
`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin_debug)`
These do not work, the output directory will still be `${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin`, anybody knows why?

I test it on Ubuntu 12.04 with CodeBlocks 10.05 and CMake 2.8.

Comment: Do you have any executable in your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: I do have target_link_libraries() and add_executable(), the executable file is generated OK and put into ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin, not the RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.